# Sliding Feature in different Iframes loaded in different ionic slides

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have an ionic page in which within ion-content I have used `ion-slides` and then in each `ion-slide` I have an `iframe` which loads a game scene. What's happening is that I am not able to slide between different iframes.
Here is the code:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-slides pager="false">
     <ion-slide>
        <iframe src="../assets/game.html" name="game_0">
     </ion-slide>
     <ion-slide>
        <iframe src="../assets/game.html" name="game_1">
     </ion-slide>
     <ion-slide>
        <iframe src="../assets/game.html" name="game_2">
     </ion-slide>
     <ion-slide>
        <iframe src="../assets/game.html" name="game_3">
     </ion-slide>
  <ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

when I set `pager="true"` then a small bullets `div` show up at the bottom through which I can slide between scenes how can I achieve the same feature without that because that `div` does not allow any interaction with the game scene it is kind of an overlay which I do not want.
Is there any other way to achieve the same sliding effects without using ionic slides
I was thinking about capturing a drag/slide event in my game scene and then raising a custom javascript event which I listen in ionic `page.ts` file is that possible to achieve?
Thanks

Comment: do you still need the abilitiy to click on the iframe?

Comment: thanks, @ic_paty for the changes suggestions

Comment: @C_Ogoo , I want the sliding ability plus interaction with the buttons inside the game scene which loads in iframe